# Photo slideshow in meteor js

Tags: meteor, slideshow

I'm looking for a slider to put on my meteor project.
I can't find one right now, I just want something to look like this http://jsworkspace.fr/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use bootstrap javascript function carousel. Look through

`http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel`

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an entire portfolio based on the bootstrap carousel :
http://RonaldPauffert.Fr

The code is available on github :
https://github.com/leroadrunner/portfolio/tree/master/client